# Saving DataFrame as ORC loses StructField metadata

Tags: apache-spark

Spark version: 2.4.4

When writing a DataFrame, I want to put some metadata on certain fields. It's important for this metadata to be persisted when I write out the DataFrame and read it again later. If I save this DataFrame as Parquet and then read it back, I see the metadata is preserved. But saving as ORC, the metadata is lost when I read the files. Here is a bit of code to show how I'm doing this (in Java):

```java
// set up schema and dataframe
Metadata myMeta = new MetadataBuilder().putString("myMetaData", "foo").build();
StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField("x", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, myMeta);
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, /* a schema using this field */);

// write it
df.write().format("parquet").save("test");

// read it again
Dataset<Row> df2 = sparkSession.read().format("parquet").load("test");

// check the schema after reading files
df2.schema().prettyJson();
df2.schema().fields()[0].metadata();
```

Using Parquet format, the metadata is deserialized as I expect. However if changed to ORC format, the metadata comes back as an empty map.

Is this a known bug in the Spark ORC implementation or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Did u try using the argument `header=True`?

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia here I'm trying to write Parquet and ORC files. I believe the `header` option would be for writing CSV files.

Comment: did u try this? `val data = spark.write.format("orc").option("header", "true")`